# Construct call to enum type as string and use in Evaluate function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, enums, evaluate

I have an Enum type in VBA and I want to use it as an index to an array. The problem is that I want to construct the Enum during runtime based on input from another function.

So I have:

```
Enum Rating_
   AAA = 1
   AA = 2
   A = 3
End Enum
```

and the following array:

```
Dim arr(1 To 3) as Double

arr(1) = 0.1
arr(2) = 0.2
arr(3) = 0.3
```

Also I have a function that outputs one of the following strings. The function's inner workings are irrelevant. For solving this problem it could be just a string (one of the Enum values):

```
funct(x,y) = "AAA"
funct(x,y) = "AA"
funct(x,y) = "A"
```

What I want to construct is a string with the Enum call such as:

```
Dim str As String
str = "Rating_." & funct(x,y)
```

and use it together with Evaluate function like:

```
Evaluate("arr(" & str & ")")
```

The above code gives an error:

Error 2029

and the following

```
Evaluate("""arr(" & str & ")""")
```

where funct(x,y) = "AAA" gives:

arr(Rating_.AAA)

as a string.

What I would like to get is 0.1 (0.2 if funct(x,y) = "AA", 0.3 if funct(x,y) = "A").

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't modify an Enum at run-time. If I understand your question correctly, I think you're looking for a dictionary...

Comment: @BigBen I don't want to modify the Enum at run-time. I just want to use it as an index to the array. I just need to construct it at run-time as a string and evaluate it.

Comment: VBA doesn't do that type of run-time code evaluation.

Comment: `Evaluate` is implicitly `Application.Evaluate` - it has nothing to do with VBA, it's just a function exposed in the Excel type library; what it *evaluates* is expressions *in the context of the host application*, e.g. named ranges, worksheet functions, etc.: it knows nothing about any VBA code.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @BigBen's comment that a dictionary might be what you're looking for, I agree with him, and here's how you'd implement it:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim Rating_ As Object
    Set Rating_ = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Rating_("AAA") = 1
    Rating_("AA") = 2
    Rating_("A") = 3

    Dim arr(1 To 3) As Double
    arr(1) = 0.1
    arr(2) = 0.2
    arr(3) = 0.3

    Dim str As String
    str = "AA" 'replace with your funct output here

    MsgBox arr(Rating_(str))    '<-- returns 0.2, no Evaluate required

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you both for this. I'm aware of the dictionary functionality but I wanted to know whether I could do this with Evaluate since it works with the Enum type if you don't want to construct it the way I want to.

Comment: @sonarclick I'm curious about your "it works with the Enum type" statement. AFAICT it doesn't, and it wouldn't make any sense that it does. `Evaluate MyEnumValue` is equivalent to `Evaluate 1` (assuming `MyEnumValue = 1`; **VBA** is evaluating the enum value *before* passing its underlying `Long` integer value to the `Evaluate` function), which outputs `1` because Excel knows how to interpret numeric literal values. If you to `Evaluate "MyEnumValue"` you get an error.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon What I mean is that if do Evaluate(arr(Rating_.AAA)) I get 0.1. This is why I asked whether I can construct the Enum at runtime using the funct(x,y) output.

Comment: @sonarclick and what I mean is that you get 0.1 because what you're giving to the Evaluate function is 0.1; VBA is evaluating arr(Rating_.AAA) to 0.1 before it passes that result to the Evaluate function.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I understand this but I thought there was a way to pass a string and have it evaluated. I have seen cases where a string like this "A" & "=" & "A" is passed and TRUE is returned. Apparently I was wrong...

Comment: @sonarclick the Excel calc engine understands `"A"="A"` perfectly fine. What you are not understanding is that the calc engine doesn't know anything about any VBA code, be it an enum or any other constant or variable - these exist in the execution context of the VBA runtime, ...I don't know how else to explain this. `Evaluate` is a member of `Excel.Application`, you can give it a string and have it evaluated *by the Excel calc engine*, yes - and it's mostly useless, because most things you can get Excel to evaluate, VBA can do too. `"A" = "A"` evaluates to `True` in VBA as well.